# How to link curses.h in Cmake?

Tags: c, windows, cmake, undefined-reference, pdcurses

I know that maybe this is a silly question but I can't see through it, I searched for other answers here, that are pretty close to mine, but, still, I didn't understand how to do it.

The problem is that I can't compile a 'C' program that uses curses.h in Windows (I'm using Clion with MinGW), when I try to do it, it gives "undefined reference" for functions in curses.h (Such as 'initscr', 'clear', ...).

Through MinGW Installation Manager I installed "mingw-32-libpdcurses" (There were two available with two different classes: dev and dll; I installed the dll one).

The CMAKEfile i'm using is this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(Project1)

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Wall -Werror -lpdcurses")

set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")

file(GLOB Project1_SRC
        "*.h"
        "*.c"
        )

add_executable(Project1 ${Project1_SRC})
```

What should I change in it in order to make it compile with curses.h?

Comment: I think you should add the library to `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS`.

Comment: Hm... you installed the dll, but not the dev package? I don't know much about MinGW, but usually you *need* the dev package to get the header files. It's curious you got a *linker* error, then, and not a compiler error about the missing header. Make sure you don't use a header from a different library version, or even a different curses distribution. That's *bound* to fail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically the same way you locate and integrate about *any* third-party library with CMake: Using one of the packaged `Find___.cmake` modules.

These are located in `share/cmake-X.Y/Modules` of your CMake installation directory. Check the files themselves for their individual documentation, and `cmake --help-command find_package` for details on how to call them.

I haven't tried the following with PDCurses on MinGW specifically, but if it doesn't work, that'd a clear bug report to Kitware (the makers of CMake):

```
find_package( Curses REQUIRED )
include_directories( ${CURSES_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
target_link_libraries( Project1 ${CURSES_LIBRARIES} )
```

The following variables are set as appropriate to tell you which header is available:

- `CURSES_HAVE_CURSES_H` for `curses.h`
- `CURSES_HAVE_NCURSES_H` for `ncurses.h`
- `CURSES_HAVE_NCURSES_NCURSES_H` for `ncurses/ncurses.h`
- `CURSES_HAVE_NCURSES_CURSES_H` for `ncurses/curses.h`

---

Additional advice:

```
file(GLOB Project1_SRC
        "*.h"
        "*.c"
        )
```

**Don't do that.**

To quote from the documentation of that very function:

> We do not recommend using GLOB to collect a list of source files from your source tree.  If no CMakeLists.txt file changes when a source is added or removed then the generated build system cannot know when to ask CMake to regenerate.

---

```
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")
```

**Don't do that either.**

You do not want *any* generated files to end up in your *source* directory (where they get in the way of your versioning system, or worse, get actually checked in to the repository). You want to generate everything in the *binary* directory, cleanly out of the way.

Comment: I modified the CMake file as [this](http://pastebin.com/YLMh98LZ) (For now i'll leave the 'GLOB' and the generated file in the source till I have resolved things with PDcurses) now it compiles but when I try to execute the program it says that I don't have "libncursesw-6.dll" in my computer.

If I try to execute one of the demos of the PDcurses it says the i lack of "libpdcurses.dll". I don't know what's wrong.

I think that I installed the library properly as you can see [here](http://i.imgur.com/qJynBnq.png)

Comment: @Aster: This means that the library is found at *compile* time (because CMake always supplies the full file path to any library), but not at *run* time (because the path information is lost in the binary). You can either a) extend the library search path (that would mean extending %PATH% for Windows, or editing /etc/ld.so.conf resp. adding to /etc/ld.so.conf.d on Linux), or b) make CMake compile the full path to the library into the executable (`set( CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH TRUE )`). But we are talking rather basic toolchain issues here; are you sure... (t.b.c.)

Comment: (ctd) ...you should be fiddling with CMake, Curses, *and* MinGW at this point, instead of familiarizing yourself a bit more with one at a time?

Comment: Thank you very much for you help and patience, I modified the %PATH% variable and now it works.

Yes, I problably shouldn't mess with many things at once but I have to for University purposes.

The problems is that I started using CLion (That uses CMake) for less than a month and before that I never used CMake or messed with minGW, I was using Code-Blocks (That doesn't use CMake) and with it was easier to build and compile but, once looked at CLion, I fell in love, it's an amazing IDE.

Thanks again for all your help!