# lncurses on Clion with Ubuntu

Tags: c++, c, clion

I'm doing a project for school with C, i'm using Clion as idee.
I already installed the ln curses in Ubuntu with the command

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses<ver>-dev
```

Using the shall, the program works!
But I would like to do some debugging with idee.
My cmake file is this

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(progetto_pipe_2 C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

add_executable(progetto_pipe_2 main.c movimento.c movimento.h grafica.c grafica.h area_gioco.c area_gioco.h)
```

If I start the application from idee , the following error appears is:

```
undefined reference to `initscr' ecc ecc
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to link curses.h in Cmake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35159634/how-to-link-curses-h-in-cmake)

Comment: Please proofread your writing; it's hard to understand. There's no letter el or space in `ncurses` and  an IDE is an acronym for "Integrated Development Environment"; it only has one e and should be in all caps. We can figure out what you mean, but it's easier if you write in a more standard way so we don't need to figure out whether "idee" is "IDE" or "idea" or something.

Comment: sorry I was wrong writing IDE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to link the library in your cmake configuration file. Check this post: [How to link curses.h in Cmake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35159634/how-to-link-curses-h-in-cmake)

Try:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12) 
project(progetto_pipe_2 C)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

# Define the target
add_executable(progetto_pipe_2 main.c movimento.c movimento.h grafica.c grafica.h area_gioco.c area_gioco.h)

# Look for the package you want to link
find_package( Curses REQUIRED )

# Include the directories of the package (to find curses.h for instance)
target_include_directories(progetto_pipe_2 PRIVATE ${CURSES_INCLUDE_DIRS} )

# Link the library
target_link_libraries(progetto_pipe_2 PRIVATE ${CURSES_LIBRARIES} )
```

Comment: /opt/clion-2018.2.6/bin/cmake/linux/bin/cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G "CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles" "/home/luca/CLionProjects/backup progetto pipe/progetto_pipe_2"
-- Found Curses: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurses.so  
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:8 (target_link_libraries):
  Cannot specify link libraries for target "progetto_pipe_2" which is not
  built by this project.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/luca/CLionProjects/backup progetto pipe/progetto_pipe_2/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".

[Finished]

Comment: You should link a library after declaring the target. See the modifications.

Comment: Thanks, but now comes the following error if I try to use debugging  ____  Error opening terminal: unknown.

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: After these commands                                                                                  initscr();
    noecho();
    curs_set(0)

Comment: You should open another question for that. That error is not related to library linkage or the cmake configuration.